# sails.js Sessions - rememberme functionality

Tags: session, sails.js, remember-me

I have been trying to implement rememberme functionality using [sails](http://sailsjs.org).  I want a session to persist until the browser is closed.  However, if a rememberme checkbox is ticked when the user logins in I want the session to persist for 30 days.  I used the remember me passport strategy from here:
https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-remember-me
but it ends up sitting on top of the sails session and the one called first ends up superseding the other.

Comment: If you use [**sails-auth**](https://github.com/tjwebb/sails-auth), passoprt.js sessions are kept alive automatically.

Comment: Yes I am using persistent sessions right now but I was wondering if there was a way to control maxage dynamically.  For instance have it set in /config/sessions to delete on window close or tab close by default unless a remember me checkbox is ticked then set the session to last for 30 days.  Maybe I dont' understand how the passport sessions integrate with the default sails one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the cookie age just before calling the login function.

I did it in my login controller -> passport.callback.

```
passport.callback(req, res, function (err, user, challenges, statuses) {
        ...

        if (req.param('remember', false) == true) {
            req.session.cookie.maxAge = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;
        }
        req.login(user, function (err) {
        ...
        }
}
```

This doesn't really feel right and, if you are sending some other cookies when logging in, it will affect their lifetime as well.

But it works and I went with it since finding documentation for sails-related stuff is like digging oil.

Also, I noticed that Passport was not destroying sessions properly upon and had to do it manually by calling `req.session.destroy();` in the logout controller.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can set the cookie yourself and set the expires manually

```
    res.cookie('userSession', {
        items: [1, 2, 3]
    }, {
        expires: new Date(Date.now() + 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
        httpOnly: true
    })
```